# How to update the state of a Toggle Button after process completion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, wxpython

I want to execute a task when a Toggle Button is clicked(on) and toggle it off after the task is completed, I execute the task in a new process because I don't want it to block the UI, `event.GetEventObject().SetValue(False)` seems to update correctly the value of the Toggle but it doesn't reflect on the UI.

```py
from  multiprocessing import Process
import time
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.toggle_button = wx.ToggleButton(self, wx.ID_ANY, "OK")
        control = Control()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOGGLEBUTTON, control.action, self.toggle_button)
        self.SetTitle("Update UI with a process")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.toggle_button, 0, 0, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

class Control():
    def update_toggle(self, duration, event):
        time.sleep(duration)
        event.GetEventObject().SetValue(False)
        print("Toggled")

    def action(self, event):
        if event.GetEventObject().GetValue():
            self.update_toggle_process = Process(target = self.update_toggle,
                                                args=(5, event,))
            self.update_toggle_process.start()
        else:
            print("UnToggled")

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

A call to `event.GetEventObject().Update()` or `event.GetEventObject().Refresh()` after changing the value of the Toggle doesn't seem to change anything.

**EDIT**:

If I use a `Thread` instead of `Process`, it works correctly, but I chose `Process` over `Thread` because I want the ability to kill it cleanly whenever I need to.

**Python version:** 3.7

**WxPython version:** 4.0.1

Answer (score 3):

You must remember, that the your update_toggle runs in a new process. Simply put, it has got a copy of data, so if you call event.GetEventObject().SetValue(False) it happens in the new process, and the original one with the Window and Button won't know.

You must somehow pass a message from the new process to the original. I would suggest that the first thing you try is:

```
        self.update_toggle_process.start()
        self.update_toggle_process.join()
        print("the process has finished")
```

This will block, but at least you will see if the "update_toggle_process" has finished and if this approach works. After that, there are a few possibilities:

- Set up a times and periodically call self.update_toggle_process.is_alive()
- Create a new thread, call the update_toggle_process.start() from it, and also join(). When finished, tell the main thread to toggle the button (remember that you may only manipulate the UI from the main thread in wx)
- Maybe you do not need a new process, a thread will be enough
- Look at the multiprocessing IPC

Comment: I suspected this, so I tried another approach which consisted in [using pushsub](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2019/03/28/wxpython-4-and-pubsub/) I didn't mentioned it in the question, but the same applies, I even tried to fire an event manually after the process completion, still not working, I chose process over thread because I want the ability to kill it whenever I need to